# How can I get the row data of the selected table header?

Tags: excel, vba

I am passing the selected table header name as a parameter in my function. I am getting `Error 424: Object Required` How can I modify my Table argument to accept `selectedTmig` as a parameter?

**Calling Code**

```
Sub foo()
Dim t As ITmProducts
Set t = New TmProductInfo

t.BuildTmServices "Account Recon"
End Sub
```

**Class Object**

```
Private Function ITmProducts_BuildTmServices(ByVal selectedTMIG As String) As Collection
    For Each TmigServiceRow In [Table1[selectedTMIG]].Rows <-- ***Error occurs here***
        ITmProducts_BuildTmProducts.Add TmigServiceRow.value
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: The table has no rows property. Try to refer to the rows of the tables `DataBodyRange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following...

```
For Each TmigServiceRow In Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(selectedTMIG).DataBodyRange
```

Change the sheet name accordingly.